# Does Yandex Browser Support Paid Extension from google chrome webstore to run?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application, yandex

Use case - Running an extension on a mobile phone, for which i found it can be done using Yandex browser.
Question - I need to check if it also supports extension which are paid in nature or need a google login to run on the browser!!

Any alternative approach to achieve external JavaScript running on top of a browser ( Yandex or Google ) over a mobile phone is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google is discontinuing all paid extensions so you might just consider all of them free.

[Source](https://www.theverge.com/2020/9/22/21451111/google-paid-chrome-extension-monetize-shut-down-end)